# Export a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Datagrid to an Excel file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, datagrid

How do I export a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Datagrid` to an Excel file in C#?
(without any 3rd party sw). Note that I am starting with a `DataGrid`, not `GridView` or `DataGridView`. I see examples for this with `DataGrid` and `DataGridView` on SO, but not `DataGrid`. I also see examples like this:
[export Datagrid to excel asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271485/export-datagrid-to-excel-asp)
which converts to html and apparently has performance issues.

Comment: If you don't like the answers to this exact question in your link, you'll need to be more specific with the problem.  What are the performance issues?  What are your performance requirements?

Comment: The message that has appeared above the question links to the same link in my original question. Maybe that is a automatically generated message. I'm not sure how to be more specific other than to restate the question. I'm looking for a solution to export a DataGrid to an Excel file in C# without using 3rd party sw or the method used in the link in the original post.

Comment: Use the method in the original post or explain what performance issues there are. I have read the code and method chosen as an answer to the original post and cannot imagine what the performance issues would be. I recommend using the code provided by @Marc Gravell and in general it is safe to assume Marc's code does not have major performance issues...