# How to get data in excel file from gridview object or database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have Data in **Database** as well as in **gridview** object. And I want to store data in a excel file using any of these two object in web application. what should i do?

Comment: Look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/271487/1079162

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to write your data to a plain text CSV file. They are really easy to write to, just like any other text file, and you can open them in Excel. However CSV files have no formatting, so you won't be able to set fonts, column widths, etc.

If you want to create a true Excel file (.xlsx), you will want to look into using the OpenXML SDK. You can read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180830%28v=office.14%29.aspx